# A few questions about being Hindu in America

Tags: belief, culture, life

I am involved in a class focused on studying different civilizations and cultures. I chose to study Indian culture and focused on religion.

If anyone is willing to give me a few answers, I would love to have personal insight about the following:

1. What is the biggest challenge about being Hindu in America? Or is there a challenge at all - maybe you have only encountered tolerance and acceptance?
2. What do you believe to be the most misunderstood part of your religion?  For example, do you encounter people who believe that people of Hindu faith are polytheistic?
3. In what ways do you think Hinduism and Indian culture have begun to influence American culture?
4. What do you believe to be the most profound idea(s) in Hinduism?
5. What would you say to a person who values the spiritual aspects of Hinduism but is an atheist? That is, can religion and spirituality be separated?
6. If you have experience with the caste system - please tell me a bit about how belonging to a caste might shape your perspective of the world, influence how other people perceive you, influence how you perceive your religion etc.

I am new to these ideas so please forgive me if I have asked anything that I shouldn't. I am incredibly fascinated by all of this and am eager to read your answers!

Comment: Hello @curiousgeorge. Welcome to Hinduism SE. Kindly limit 1 or 2 questions per post. Your question touches various topics and is considered too broad for this site.

Comment: please reframe the question, broad questions are closed by the community!

Comment: As @PratikBhat says, questions on this site are only supposed to be about one topic, so this is too broad for the site, and in any case most or all of your questions are too personal and opinion-based for the site.  You may want to turn this into a survey and ask people on the Hinduism.SE chatroom to take it, since this isn't really the sort of thing that's on-topic for the actual site.

Comment: In any case, just to help you out I thought I would answer your questions in a word document: http://gdurl.com/zlTF

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think you have bad opinion on RSS.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, I do have a negative opinion of RSS, for two reasons.  First because they're against the caste system, and second because they destroyed Babri Masjid.  However I don't live in India so it's possible that I have a distorted impression of RSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good book available for free download that speaks directly to the many misconceptions propagated in the US about Hinduism. It is "Invading the Sacred: An Analysis of Hinduism Studies in America" go to http://rajivmalhotra.com/books/invading-sacred/ for a free download. If you want a good introduction to Hinduism, in all it's flavors, I would recommend "The Spiritual Heritage of India" by Swami Prabhavananda. Available from Amazon, hardcopy and Kindle versions.